# Passing DATEDIFF interval as user defined function argument?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I want to write a function to return datediff ignoring weekends on SQL Server.
Is it allowed to pass interval as an argument on my user defined function, as following?
SQL Server is saying "Invalid parameter 1 specified for datediff."

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DATEDIFFWD](@interval varchar(2), @ini datetime, @end datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @output int
    SET @output = DATEDIFF(@interval, @ini, @end)
    IF (@interval = 'hh') SET @output = @output - (DATEDIFF(WK, @ini, @end) * 48)
    IF (@interval = 'dd') SET @output = @output - (DATEDIFF(WK, @ini, @end) * 2)
    RETURN @output
END
```

Comment: You can't. But since you're using `if @interval = 'hh'...` you might as well add `if @interval = 'hh' @output = datediff(hour, ); @output = @output - ...`

Comment: Aside: `DateDiff` returns the number of _boundaries_ crossed in the specified units, e.g. the number of days between `2018-01-01T00:30:00` and `2018-01-01T23:30:00` is `0` and between `2018-01-01T23:30:00` and `2018-01-02T00:30:00` is `1`. Always using the number of `week` boundaries crossed and multiplying by a factor to arrive at smaller units, e.g. `hour`, is unusual. Going the other way, e.g. getting the difference in minutes and dividing by `1200` to get days removes the boundary crossing aspect of `DateDiff` for `day`.

Answer (score 4):

You could rewrite it as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DATEDIFFWD](@interval varchar(2),
                                   @ini datetime, @end datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT CASE @interval 
      WHEN 'hh' THEN DATEDIFF(hh, @ini, @end) - ((DATEDIFF(WK, @ini, @end) * 48))
      WHEN 'dd' THEN DATEDIFF(dd, @ini, @end) - ((DATEDIFF(WK, @ini, @end) * 2))
    END
    );
END
```

Please note that [scalar function could be inlined starting from SQL Server 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=azuresqldb-current)

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=334371777f2f50e69cad1cbd964edbd0)**

For better performance I would use table function instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DATEDIFFWD](@interval varchar(2),
                                   @ini datetime, @end datetime)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT CASE @interval 
     WHEN 'hh' THEN DATEDIFF(hh, @ini, @end) - ((DATEDIFF(WK, @ini, @end) * 48))
     WHEN 'dd' THEN DATEDIFF(dd, @ini, @end) - ((DATEDIFF(WK, @ini, @end) * 2))
    END AS r
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`DATEDIFF` [will not accept user-defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) variable equivalents for the `DATEPART`. You'll have to concatenate this in dynamic SQL or use some other logic to separate that variable outside of `DATEDIFF`. Also, I wouldn't use `varchar(2)` on the `@interval` mainly because [it's a bad habit one should kick.](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations).

Comment: I'll take it since it doesn't happen often @SeanLange haha

Comment: You cannot use dynamic SQL inside function

Comment: @LukaszSzozda but you could use dynamic sql to build  string and execute the result to the output parameter.

Comment: What's the point of which function? The UDF or datediff? I don't understand your comment. I wouldn't write this UDF in the first place personally.

Comment: @scsimon The point is that OP wants to use function to encapsulate some logic. As you cannot use dynamic SQL inside function(without "workarounds") how it will help him?

Comment: Now I understand what you are getting at and that's a fair point, if your exclude the work arounds.